# How do you create multiple vectors (rnorms) in R?

Tags: r, vector

I'm new to programming so excuse the simple question.
I'm having trouble creating multiple rnorms:

```
vector_b <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 100, sd = 10)
```

I would like to create `vector_b` 100 times i.e. 100 length.

Comment: `replicate(100, rnorm(n = 100, mean = 100, sd = 10))` might be what you're looking for

Comment: However, i can't seem to get it to work for a set.seed function?

Comment: Is there any possibility of using a for loop instead?

Comment: The answer given above is correct for your case and set.seed works perfectly. If you need to create THE SAME vector 100 times just do `matrix(vector_b, ncol=100)`

Comment: `replicate(100, vector_b)`